# How to zoom out UIImageView content(image) on scroll of UITableView?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, animation, uiimageview

I am trying to achieve this effect:

https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/124059/screenshots/3727352/400.gif

for this I'm doing:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CardCell", for: indexPath) as! CardTableViewCell

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.3, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.1, initialSpringVelocity: 0.5, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
        cell.coverImageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.7, y: 0.7)
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

but this code resizes the UIImageView frame, not the image inside of UIImageView.

How can I improve my code?

Comment: You need a view holding it to clip/mask the imageView.  And then set the transform to something like cell.coverImageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.5, y:1.5) and in the animation do cell.coverImageView.transform = .identity

Comment: You would scale it up in willDisplayCell maybe but you might have to check that it is on screen in scrollviewDidScrolll to call the animation

Comment: @agibson007 Thanks! But how can I combine `let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CardCell", for: indexPath) as! CardTableViewCell` part with `didScroll` part? How I'll now which image to zoom out, from which indexPath.row?

Comment: You would have to grab all visible cells and find the one in the center of the view

Comment: @agibson007 I get again transformation of the frame of UIImageView, not the UIImage =/

Comment: Is this what you want? http://imgur.com/yumjkSM

Comment: @agibson007 yes! Can you show me the code, please?

Comment: yes. I am going on a run but will be back very shortly. I just did not want to answer unless it looked right.

Comment: @agibson007 thanks! Will wait!

Comment: if you find that to be correct please mark it correct.  thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to mess with the frame of the imageView to make it redraw and look like the content mode is changing.  You can do this manipulating the frame or the constraints and have it masked inside another view.  Run the example and let me know.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var imageView = UIImageView()
    var maskView = UIView()
    var frame : CGRect = .zero

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        view.layoutIfNeeded()
        imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 40, width: view.bounds.width-40, height: view.bounds.height/2))
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "img")
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill


        maskView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 40, width: view.bounds.width-40, height: view.bounds.height/2))
        maskView.addSubview(imageView)
        maskView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        maskView.layer.cornerRadius = 6
        self.view.addSubview(maskView)

        //manipulate the imageView to make the content mode seem to change
        // and have it redraw itself
        frame = imageView.frame
        var newFrame = frame
        newFrame.size.height += newFrame.height
        imageView.frame = newFrame
        imageView.center = maskView.center


        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: maskView.frame.maxY + 60, width: view.bounds.width - 40, height: 40))
        button.setTitle("Animate", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(.blue, for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.pressed), for: .touchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(button)


        let AnotherButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: button.frame.maxY + 20, width: view.bounds.width - 40, height: 40))
        AnotherButton.setTitle("Reset", for: .normal)
        AnotherButton.setTitleColor(.blue, for: .normal)
        AnotherButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.reset), for: .touchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(AnotherButton)
    }

    func pressed() {
        //animate
        // screw around with the imageView back to the original frame
        // you could also do this with the height constraints if it was constraint based
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1.0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
            self.imageView.frame = self.maskView.bounds
        }, completion: nil)

    }

    func reset() {
        //reset big frame
        var newFrame = frame
        newFrame.size.height += newFrame.height

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1.0, initialSpringVelocity: 1.0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
            self.imageView.frame = newFrame
            self.imageView.center = self.maskView.center
        }, completion: nil)

    }

}
```

Result:
[image: Zoom]